# May one violate a derabonon to preform a Bris

Tags: halacha, brit-milah, derabanan

May one violate a rabbinic prohibition (such as carrying a knife in a Karmilis on Shabbos) in order to perform a Bris Milah? (A Karmilis is a domain which a person can't carry stuff into or from a private domain on shabbat)

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks for the edit. David Feigen, a good number of your questions do not adequately explain what you mean. No one here reads minds (or at least most of us don't) and the majority of people who come across this won't know what a _karm'lis_ is. Please explain, in your question posts, what you're asking.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/bris-on-shabbos

Comment: There is the shittah of Rebbi Eliezer

Comment: Sam 2, are you referring to rabbi eliezer the tannaic sage?

Answer (score 3):

[Rambam Sefer Ahava Hilchos Mila 2:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=8197&rid=1141) says one may not carry the Mila knife on Shabbos even in a area where it is a D'Rabanan since it is possible to bring before Shabbos.

> כיצד הרי שלא מצאו סכין אין עושין סכין בשבת ולא מביאין אותו ממקום
>   למקום. ואפילו מבוי שאינו מעורב אין מביאין אותו מחצר לחצר. ואין עירוב
>   מדבריהם נדחה מפני הבאת הסכין הואיל ואפשר להביאו מערב שבת

[Rabbi Eliezer Melamud](http://ph.yhb.org.il/01-09-11/) maintains that in extenuating circumstances the first choice would be to get a non Jew to carry it for you. If that is not an option a Jew may carry it with a Shinui in a Karmelis.

> לדעת רוב הפוסקים, גם 'שבות דשבות' שנעשה על ידי יהודי התירו חכמים לצורך
>   מצווה. למשל, אם צריך להביא סכין דרך כרמלית לצורך ברית מילה, ואין שם
>   גוי שאפשר לבקש זאת ממנו, מותר לישראל לטלטל את הסכין בשינוי, שבאופן זה
>   הוא 'שבות דשבות'. ואמנם יש מחמירים בזה, אולם בשעת הצורך לשם מצווה מותר
>   גם לישראל לעשות 'שבות דשבות'.

Comment: But what if you couldn't bring it before shabbat.

Comment: @DavidFeigen I'm not sure what you are asking. The Rambam couldn't be clearer.

Comment: If for instance you couldn't find the knife until shabbat started, then you can't say you could've brought it before shabbat if you didn't have it!